# Style for web application grid

Tags: css, grid, styles

I'm working on a small bugtracking system which shows a list of bugs. For the overview I want to use a grid - now I only need a style.

Of course I won't copy the whole style from anyone else, but I just want to know which type of styles you like. Do you have any other great style?

What do you think about the styles on [this site](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/06/4_new_grouping_grid_skins_vist.html).
Do you like the [Component art grid styles](http://www.componentart.com/webui/demos/demos_control-specific/grid/design/default/WebForm1.aspx)?
What about the [styles from telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS table gallery](http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/) can be a great source of inspiration.

The CSS Table Gallery is a showcase of how CSS and data tables can work together to create usable and pretty results.

Comment: Yes! a new record: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36318/whats-the-longest-interval-between-an-answer-being-posted-and-accepted/36325#comment469716_36318